# Getting error in Android using kSOAP2

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Error I am getting is this

**org.ksoap2.SoapFault cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject**

```
public final static String URL = "http://23.253.164.20:8096/login.asmx";
public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://23.253.164.20:8096";
public static final String SOAP_ACTION_PREFIX = "http://23.253.164.20:8096/getName";
private static final String METHOD = "getName";

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private String resp;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress("Loading contents..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
            try {
                // SoapEnvelop.VER11 is SOAP Version 1.1 constant
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
                //bodyOut is the body object to be sent out with this envelope
                envelope.bodyOut = request;
                HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                try {
                    transport.call(NAMESPACE + SOAP_ACTION_PREFIX + METHOD, envelope);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //bodyIn is the body object received with this envelope
                if (envelope.bodyIn != null) {
                    //getProperty() Returns a specific property at a certain index.
                    SoapPrimitive resultSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) ((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn)
                            .getProperty(0);
                    resp=resultSOAP.toString();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                resp = e.getMessage();
            }
            return resp;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
            // In this example it is the return value from the web service
            textView.setText(result);
        }
```

Possibility checked

> 1) Internet permission given
>
> 2) Ksoap2 library imported
>
> 3) server side method is running (you can the URL)
>
> 4) Not running on the emulator instead on the mobile phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some bugs in whole code.

- there is no method "getName" - it looks like You meant "getGreetingForName" but i'm not sure becouse You have'nt provided param "stringName",
- NAMESPACE = "http://23.253.164.20:8096/"; - add slash on the end,
- transport.call(NAMESPACE + SOAP_ACTION_PREFIX + METHOD, envelope);
- that is not proper - becouse method called here is "http://23.253.164.20:8096http://23.253.164.20:8096/getNamegetName"

see also my answer to Your second posting - there is working code of login:
[getting parameter error in ksoap 2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746895/getting-parameter-error-in-ksoap-2-android/29756158#29756158)

Regards,
Marcin